# How to implement STI (in Rails) in a lookup table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, sti

I want to have two layers of STI. The first layer is working but am unsure how to have the first model lookup to another table also using STI. Example:

```
class Instrument < ActiveRecord::Base

end

class Guitar < Instrument

end

class Piano < Instrument

# and so on...
```

Ok. But I want to track categories of instruments so I can tell their type:

```
class InstrumentType < ActiveRecord::Base

end

class StringInstrumentType < InstrumentType

end

# etc.
```

So... our Guitar model becomes:

```
class Guitar < Instrument
  belongs_to :string_intrument_type
end

class StringInstrumentType < InstrumentType
  has_many :guitars
end
```

How do I implement this? What do I name the foreign-key column and how do I tell Rails/AR what to do?

Am I way off base here?

This scenario is invented but we are finding some real-world refactoring wants us to move in this direction.

Answer (score 0):

Your first STI makes sense, the other one does not. On the abstract level, strings are rather an instance of an `InstrumentType`, not its subclass. It seems to me that you might rather use sth like:

```
class Instrument < ActiveRecord::Base
  # abstract
end

class StringInstrument < Instrument
  # abstract
end

module Instrument::Keyboard
end

class Guitar < StringInstrument
end

class Piano < StringInstrument
  include Instrument::Keyboard
end
```

or similar. Obviously it depends A LOT on your actual code. In example you gave instrument types are rather constant in time, hence it is possible to use inheritance.

My guess is however, that your types are dynamic and can be added by clients. What you are looking for then is probably a tree structure. So every type has its parent and each parent type might have couple of children. You can then simply do `Instrument belongs_to instrument_type` and point to some InstrumentType tree leaf.